# Silverlight: Web Service Call JSON Error

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, web-services, asynchronous

OK, so I have no idea why this isn't working. I've found 4 different tutorials/examples of calling a JSON web service asynchronously within Silverlight, and all of them use the same format / logic as I am. On the line "using (streamCommunities = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult))" it is throwing the error I attached at the bottom, an ArgumentException saying it doesn't like the asyncResult. Why is this if every other example I've found uses the same logic?

```
    private void GetSource(object state)
    {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(MyValidUri));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCommunityCallBack), request);
    }

    private void ReadCommunityCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {            
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        using (Stream outStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult))
        {
          // DO STUFF HERE
        }
    }
```

And the error is here:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
   StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at cenTabbedFeed.MainPage.ReadCommunityCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__18(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Like I said, I've been scouring examples and trying to find an answer on MSDN and I'm stuck and frustrated.

-Thanks in advance
RJ

Comment: try to catch the exception by placing it in a try/catch block. That error message tells that you are not catching the error. If you catch it, maybe you have more info about it.

Comment: But maybe you have more info about it. The problem may be on the server side.

Comment: It tells me that error that I posted... e.Message = Value does not fall within the expected range. That doesn't solve the error.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if the web service isn't handling this... I know the Uri is valid, and I'm POSTing correctly...

Comment: Do U have access to the Server code? Or better, can U debug the server code?

Comment: Nope, I wonder why it's saying it's out of range. The ContentLength is returning as -1 which isn't good... I'm still digging.

Comment: I think you're right though, I think it is server side:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7de1x8cb.aspx 
says the error is "asyncResult was not returned by the current instance from a call to BeginGetRequestStream."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your request method is `POST` but you don't post anything. Either write something to RequestStream or change your method to `GET`.

**--EDIT--**

You can post some string to server as below

```
byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3");
request.ContentType = "application/www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = buf.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(buf,0,buf.Length);
```

Comment: So I have a custom class with the post data, how do I write it to the request stream? StreamWriter class and a ToString() method?

Comment: To post something, you have to add a body to the request. It's like a query string: key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3. The framework already abstracts the stream handling for you.

Comment: I used a DataContractJsonSerializer and a WriteJsonToStream() method, I thought you weren't supposed to specify ContentLength in Silverlight because it was automatically handled?

Comment: Plus it's async so I have to use the Begin... and End... methods and pass states. But thanks for the help. I think I know how to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

Uve got the wrong one. Ur using `BeginGetResponse`. I just had same problem in ACW. changed it to `BeginGetRequestStream` instead, all is well :)

Comment: Nope, actually it was because I was dumb and didn't know how to use a WebRequest with a POST method. BeginGetResponse is what I used when I finished. It was writing to the stream and passing states that I was messing up on.